# VUE 2 : Referencing VUE component inside another component's <template>. Module not found exception

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

i have been googling around for quite some time now to figure out WHY.. my modal component won't get recognized inside my vieworder.vue component.

I'm receiving :

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?
type=script&index=0!./src/components/ViewOrder.vue

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Modal.vue' in 
'C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx\src\components'
```

**ViewOrder.vue - usage of modal :**

```
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" v-if="order">
        <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
        </modal>   
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import * as types from '../store/mutationtypes'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'

export default {
    name: 'ViewOrder',
    components: {
        'modal': Modal
    }
    ....
```

**Modal.vue**

```
<template>
    ....
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "modal"
    }
</script>
```

**Main.js - Reference :**

```
....
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'
import ViewOrder from './components/ViewOrder.vue'
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'`

Should be `import Modal from './Modal.vue'`

You're already in the `components` folder when inside `ViewOrder.vue`

Comment: Oh goodness.... I've tried "Modal.vue", "../components/Modal.vue", and all other possible scenarios.. EXCEPT.. the right one !

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch... Sometimes... solution is way, way easier for others to find than myself.. :)

Comment: Definitely you get stuck in an issue sometimes and very rarely forget to check things that you think are 100% working.